# Access-Control-Allow-Origin on SAPUI5 today

Tags: sapui5

I have been running a SAP UI5 application for a year with out any problems. But today it changed and gave me Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

This the code. I have only tried to change the version but it does not help.

```
    <script
        id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/1.38.12/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.layout, sap.ui.table,sap.m,sap.ui"
        data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
        data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"VendorApprovalComponent.DO_OrgTransord" : "./" }' >
    </script>
```

The errors that I'm getting is the following.

```
    XMLHttpRequest cannot load sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/1.38.12/resources/sap/ui/layout/library-preload.json. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'CUSTOMERURL' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 404.send @ sap-ui-core.js:126ajax @ sap-ui-core.js:126q.sap.preloadModules @ sap-ui-core.js:174(anonymous function) @ sap-ui-core.js:174each @ sap-ui-core.js:115q.sap.registerPreloadedModules @ sap-ui-core.js:174success @ sap-ui-core.js:174p @ sap-ui-core.js:126fireWith @ sap-ui-core.js:126h3 @ sap-ui-core.js:126(anonymous function) @ sap-ui-core.js:126send @ sap-ui-core.js:126ajax @ sap-ui-core.js:126q.sap.preloadModules @ sap-ui-core.js:174(anonymous function) @ sap-ui-core.js:833each @ sap-ui-core.js:115constructor @ sap-ui-core.js:833(anonymous function) @ sap-ui-core.js:949applyAMDFactoryFn @ sap-ui-core.js:174(anonymous function) @ sap-ui-core.js:174t1 @ sap-ui-core.js:174sap.ui.define @ sap-ui-core.js:174s1 @ sap-ui-core.js:174r1 @ sap-ui-core.js:174q.sap.require @ sap-ui-core.js:174(anonymous function) @ sap-ui-core.js:1761
sap-ui-core.js:160 2016-11-03 11:32:52.176935 failed to preload 'sap.ui.layout.library-preload': NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on
```

My webserver is a SAP NW JAVA server running behind a ICM firewall.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse with the SAPUI5 plugin ?

Comment: Is this a problem while developing locally or in your productive environment?